# Python appending to list will remove unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have string: a więc

when I print it all ok, but when I append to list it changes to `u'a wi\u0119c'`.
Then I am trying to save to file (using `json.dumps` because there is many words in list) and it stays `u'a wi\u0119c'`.

How to fix to make the `u'a wi\u0119c'` to a więc?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import json
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

def scrapsl():
    wordlist = []
    deflist = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://sjp.pl/slownik/lp.phtml?page=1').read(), "html.parser")
    nextpage = soup.find_all('b')[1].a.get('href')
    for i in range(2, 52):
        wordlist.append(unicode(soup.find_all('tr')[i].td.text))
        print(unicode(soup.find_all('tr')[i].td.text))
        sp = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://sjp.pl/' + str(wordlist[(len(wordlist) - 1)]).replace(' ', "+")).read(), "html.parser")
        deflist.append({wordlist[(len(wordlist) - 1)]: sp.find_all('p')[3].text})
        print(str(i) + "\\52")
    print wordlist
    writelist = []
    writelist.append(wordlist)
    writelist.append(deflist)
    ftw = open("slownik.txt", 'w')
    ftw.write(json.dumps(writelist))
    ftw.close()
scrapsl()
```

Thanks

Comment: You are swapping a string with its textual representation...

Comment: ok but how to fix?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Its a dictionary scrapper. I tried other fixes so sorry for shitty code. https://pastebin.com/xUDm08eh

Comment: They're the same. Why does it matter how it looks if it's the same thing in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, and you cannot fix it because this is by design in Python 2.x. When printing a list, each value is processed by the `repr` function first, so you're printing a list of `repr`'d values, which may be different from what you see after `print`ing each of them, because `print(value)` outputs `str(value)`, not `repr(value)`.

If you absolutely need to see the actual values (that is, `str(value)`, not `repr(value)`), just upgrade to Python 3.x.

Comment: ... Ok then. But when I will load the txt later using json library, can It be parsed back to its normal form?

Comment: @MakaloneLOgman, of course, Python handles this automatically, you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, but still - I will need it in lists (TKinter) later, there isnt any fix?

Comment: @MakaloneLOgman, if you're so uncomfortable with this (no, you cannot escape it in Python 2), you can upgrade to Python 3, which has built-in support for Unicode.

Comment: in py3 without any extra code it will work? (I know that urllib2 has to be replaced with requests), but I mean the unicode list and file.

Comment: @MakaloneLOgman, according to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html), "Since Python 3.0, the language features a `str` type that contain Unicode characters, meaning any string created using "unicode rocks!", 'unicode rocks!', or the triple-quoted string syntax is stored as Unicode."

Comment: great thanks. (empty something cuz min 15 characters/comment)